# laravel filter the results based upon attributes

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, vuejs2, laravel-query-builder

I have one main tabel called "motors" and their attributes i am saving in the sub table "motor_attributes". The atributes are dynamic and they can hold any id and value. 
 The relationship is one to many relationship. 
The problem is i cant search any of the attribute. It gives me the same parent table items 
"enteries".

I want to make it more clear. Every time it gives  me 6 enteries. Even though if i change the value of the  $request->get('body_condition'). manually. because its query string. 
And i want to filter motors best upon these attributes.
Any help will be appreciated.
It just hide the attributes not the main Advertisement.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance

```````````

```
        $perPage = 20;
        $motorQuery = Motor::with(['advertisementPhotos', 'country', 'city', 'customer.dealer','favouriteAd', 'adAttributes' => function ($query) use ($request){

             // dd($request->get('body_condition'));
             $query->where('integer_value',$request->get('body_condition'));
             $query->with('attribute');
             $query->with('adAttributeValue');
             $query->where('show_listing_page',1);
        //;
        //  return $query->take(2);

          }])
        ->where('status', 1)
        ->where('date_expiry', '>=', date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00');


    if (request()->filled('city')) {
        $motorQuery->where('city', request()->get('city'));
    }
    if (request()->filled('keywords')) {
        $motorQuery->where('title', 'like', '%' . request()->get('keywords') . '%');
    }
    if (request()->filled('from_price')) {
        $motorQuery->where('price', '>=', request()->get('from_price') );
    }
    if (request()->filled('to_price')) {
        $motorQuery->where('price', '<=', request()->get('to_price') );
    }


    if (request()->hasCookie('country')) {
        $motorQuery->where('country', request()->cookie('country')->first()->id);
    }

    $data['allMotors'] =  $allMotors = $motorQuery->orderBy('featured', 'desc')->orderBy('date_posted', 'desc')->paginate($perPage);
```

```

Comment: no body is here for help ?

Comment: If you want to filter data based on attribute table also put it in join rather than in WITH. With will filter attribute itself table only.

Comment: I've answered. Please check and let me know if it is work for you. I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks jinandra. You are solution is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as I see it from your code, you are trying to filter motors here and using the filters in the wrong place.

The filters in the with clause will only filter the relations to be eager loaded, not the parent model.

To filter the parent model while being in Eloquent syntax, use "has" or the shortcut "whereHas":

```
$perPage = 20;
$bodyCondition = request('body_condition');
$motorQuery = Motor::with(['advertisementPhotos', 'country', 'city', 'customer.dealer','favouriteAd', 'adAttributes.attribute', 'adAttributes.adAttributeValue'])
    ->whereHas('adAttributes', function ($q) use ($bodyCondition) {
        $q->where('integer_value', $bodyCondition)
          ->where('show_listing_page',1);
    })
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->where('date_expiry', '>=', date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try using join for attribute filter. Also if any table related to attribute and you want some data from those table also put in join these tables too. Try something like this:

```
$motorQuery = Motor::with(['advertisementPhotos', 'country', 'city', 'customer.dealer','favouriteAd'])
            ->join('ad_attribute_value', 'ad_attribute_value.motor_id', '=', 'motor.id')
            ->where(function($query) use ($request){
                       if($request->get('body_condition') != '')
                           $query->where('integer_value', '=', $request->get('body_condition'))
            })
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->where('date_expiry', '>=', date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00');
```

See if it work for you.

Comment: By the way you mixed query builder with the eloquent.